# Magento 2 check which catalog rule is applied to cart product

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2, catalog-price-rules, programmatically

I have created 3 catalog rules for category.

1. Shoes Category:  5% Off ,  Catalog Rule Name:  Shoes Offer
2. Toys Category:   10% Off,  Catalog Rule Name:  Toys Offer
3. Fashion Accessories: 8% Off, Catalog Rule Name:  Fashion Acc. Offer

So all the product of that categories are showing discounted price in category.
On cart page i want to show which catalog rule is applied to item.

Is there any way to check on cart item that which catalog rule is applied to it?

How can i check which catalog rule is applied to item and how much discount is applied?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304062/how-to-get-the-catalog-price-rule-programmatically-in-magento2

```
 /**
 * @param $productId
 * @param $customerGroupId
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCatalogPriceRuleFromProduct($productId, $customerGroupId)
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    $product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($productId);

    $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
    $store = $this->_store_manager->getStore($storeId);
    $websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    $date = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
    $dateTs = $date->gmtDate();

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule
     */
    $resource = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');

    $rules = $resource->getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);

    return $rules;
}
```